# How to encode cyrillic in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

what's up? :-)
I have one problem and i hope you can help me with it.

One friend of mine have a simple solid html website and i implemented little php; CRUD system for articles... problem i came across is placing and getting cyrillic characters from mysql database.

What i want to achive is next:
In the main navigation there are some separated sections, whose names, ids and item's order i want to place in mysql and than to pull names and to put each name as a link. Names are supposed to be cyrillic characters.

The problem comes when i, using php `mysql_fetch_assoc` function, try to display names which are inserted with cyrillic characters in database row, collation of row is `utf8_general_ci`, and i end with `?????` insted of original characters. If i submit cyrillic characters via submit form to mysql it shows something like this Ð£.

How can i solve this, thanks in advance!? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you call this after connecting to database.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Also make sure that HTML file has charset meta tag set to UTF-8 or send header before output.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");  
Did the job. Thanks. :)  
And about html it has meta tag set to UTF-8.

Comment: executing set names is not recommended. please see my answer.

Comment: Nothing, mysql_set_charset is identical with mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8"), read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html, set charset is safer, but since he knows collation it is practically the same.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem until I encoded the 'Collation' column in my table to 'utf8_bin'.

Answer (score 1):

if its really mysql fetch assoc messing up you should try:
[mysql-set-charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

from the docs:

> Note:
>
> This is the preferred way to change
> the charset. Using mysql_query() to
> execute SET NAMES .. is not
> recommended.

also make sure your files are saved as utf8 and check [iconv_set_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php) / [iconv_get_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php)

Comment: Thanks. :) I'll see about these functions.
Edit: I did it with: mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con); Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having more complex issues with **legacy project** upgrades from versions before PHP 5.6 and MYSQL 5.1 to PHP 7 & Latest MySQL/Percona/MariaDB etc...

If the project uses **utf8_encode($value)** you can either try removing the function from the value being prepared and use the accepted answer for setting UTF-8 encoding for all input.

--- OR ---

Try replacing **utf8_encode($value)** with **mb_convert_encoding($value, 'utf-8')**

**PDO USERS**

If you are using PDO here are two ways how to set utf8:

```
$options = [
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
];

new \PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options);
```

--- OR ---

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;'

new \PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
```

I can confirm that **mb_convert_encoding($value, 'utf-8')** to SQL table using **utf8_unicode_ci** works for *Cyrillic* and *Umlaut*.