# Cyrillic does not show in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I insert cyrillic text through PHP it inserts a row but with empty records:

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));
}

if($link->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO applications (firstname, lastname, university, specialty, course, hobby, motivation, phone, email) VALUES ('да', 'да', 'да', 'да', 'да', 'да', 'да', 'да', 'да')");

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

When I remove the /* change character set to utf8 */ the entries are symbols... Where is the problem?

Comment: Does your field in the table have the correct encoding?

Comment: I tried both utf8_general_ci and cp1251_general_ci

Comment: Is your PHP file saved as utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

Call this after you connect to your database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534410/how-to-encode-cyrillic-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm not using the mysql function but mysqli, so this will do nothing