# Php mysql returning?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, when I try to echo a cyrillic character, it return like ????

Here's code

```
<?
    include('db.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE reference=1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

            $rows[] = json_encode($row);

        } 
        $items = implode(',',$rows);
        echo '['.$items.']';
    }else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }

?>
```

Any idea?

Collation : utf8_general_ci

And db.php:

```
<?    
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "Conqwe333!";    
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,"test");   
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Worked after `<? $conn->set_charset("utf8");?>`

Comment: what is the collation of the mysql table menu_items?

Comment: do you have proper "bom" and headers on the file?

Comment: do not use short tags `<?` with PHP - you will be in troubles if this gets turned off in php.ini

Comment: try to call `SET NAMES='UTF8';` sql query after connect.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Since PHP 5.4 short tags are always active regardless of the `short_open_tag` setting (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: @vp_arth did, and still ????? is returned

Comment: @ChrisChong, are you sure, that your db data correctly written?

Comment: @holodoc I do not think so. Read the docs you liked to again, more carefuly

Comment: @holodoc, it's correct just for `<?= ?>` syntax

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I misread the code.

Answer (score 2):

You should set collation per connection:

[mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Also you can perform sql

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

but it's not recommended

---

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Indeed, doing like $conn->set_charset("utf8"); worked!

Comment: I was wrong with `set names` syntax, sorry. Anyway there is a better way :)

Answer (score 2):

Add before your `$sql`

```
$conn->query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

You can read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Also you will need to set proper header for browser. You can do it by serveral ways for example in meta html tag or using `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Bulgarian and UTF8, same will work for Russian and other languages, just change "bg" to proper string.

I do not recommend you to use cp1251, because it breaks unexpectedly with apache mod_rewrite and other tools like this.

You need to do following checks:

- Check if your database / table collation is some UTF8. It could be utf8_general_ci or Bulgarian - difference is minimal and is more sorting related. (utf8_general_ci is perfectly OK)
- Check you have following statement executed right after connect - `set names UTF8;`. You can do `$mysqli->query("set names utf8");`
- Make sure you have proper "tags". Here an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang='bg' xml:lang='bg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Нов сайт :)</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
```

- You can include UTF8 "BOM" on the html, but it works pretty well without it. I usually work without "BOM", and when I want to be 100% complaint, I create an include file `bom.php` that contain just the BOM symbol and include it prior HTML template in normal PHP way, e.g. `include "bom.php"`.

Hope this helps, if not, please comment.

**EDIT:**

Someone suggested you must be sure if your data is properly stored in MySQL. Easiest way is to open PHP MySQL Admin. If Cyrillic is shown there, all is OK.

Comment: I just used $conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: That's OK, but if not work, try with `set names utf8`. set names changes not just the charset, but 3-4 configuration values at once.

Comment: also note, if no proper HTML tags are found, Cyrillic will be not shown, unless you click on "charset" menu of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is a step back, try to first encode the cyrillic characters correctly: [How to encode cyrillic in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534410/how-to-encode-cyrillic-in-mysql)